# Can I specify a document type with a doubled suffix?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Our app has a document type which uses the suffix `.sgb`.  It's a package type, so in a lot of cases users zip them up and send them as `.sgb.zip`.We can't ask our users to rename them to `.sgbz`.  I've added `.zip` files as a document type to our app, and it's opening the `.sgb.zip` files; but the OS is offering my app to the user to open all `.zip` files.  I've tried specifying `sgb.zip` as a new document type, but it just gets ignored.  Can I specify a document type with the suffix `.sgb.zip` somehow, or do I have to open all `.zip`s and see whether they have a `.sgb` file in them?

Comment: why dont your check if your file name contains `.sgb.zip` to check whether it is `.sgb.zip` or not

Comment: The problem is that the OS thinks my app can open all files with a .zip suffix.  By the time it gets to my app, it's too late.

Comment: Because the OS has already offered to open the file in my app.